# bypass application.html.erb in Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view

I have an application.html.erb file which sets out layout for every pages in my app (header, footer etc.) like a typical Rails app.

However, I would like to have a landing page which I don't want to use this file. How should I bypass application.html.erb?

Thank you.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Use

```
render :layout => false
```

or

```
render :layout => 'whatever'
```

in your action. If you are using a separate `LandingController` you simply can create a *app/views/layouts/landing.html.erb* which will be picked up or you can override the layout via

```
class LandingController < ApplicationController
  layout 'whatever'
  ...
end
```

Comment: But can we also ask actions in this controller? if not then how router will not , that I am going to for this controller?

Answer (score 6):

You can set a layout in your render function:

```
render {other arguments}, :layout => :homepage
```

You can also set that option to `false` to not use any layout at all.

You can do something similar if you want an entire controller to use a custom layout:

```
class MyController < ApplicationController

    layout :homepage

    #...
end
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 3):

In the controller that renders the view, change the render to:

```
render :layout => false
```

You can read more about options to render and how to work with layouts at the [Rails guide to render and layouts](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html).