# Can I break away from rails asset pipeline?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

In my Rails webapp I would like to have a view that only gets its css from a specific css/scss file. I have tried several suggested solutions on here but none to my avail.

However, would I be able to place the example.css.scss file outside of the assets/stylesheets directory and restrict the view file example.html.erb to the example.css.scss styling only for example.html.erb?

From what I understand by reading [rails asset pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) all files in the myapp/app/assets directory inherits its css rules from the application.css file and as well the corresponding css file when the controller is generated creating a view file, css file, etc. etc.

I've created a webapp using Ruby on Rails. The app is almost done and is staged. I had an idea that a landing page would be a nice opener to the webapp.

My goal is to create a landing page for webapp. The landing page consists of a background image with a text centered link, which I would like to link to the home page of the webapp and not receive any styling from the application.css file.

Basically I want this view file to have nothing to do with the application.css file.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *My goal is to create a landing page for my app.* - Why do you need a framework for a landing page?

Comment: @Mr.Alien unless the framework is for the app

Comment: @alexanderbird Yea, unless it's for the app

Comment: Im not sure I understand the question. I've created a web app using Ruby on Rails. The app is almost done and is staged. I had an idea that a landing page would be a nice opener to the website. I apologize I believe I threw you off by just saying 'my app.' I should have said website/app.

Comment: @charlie.brown Add that couple of sentences to your question. It will make it easier for other users to understand what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

While there may be reasons to use a totally different css file that's not part of the asset pipeline (e.g. landing page working while rails is restarting, keeping landing page lightweight, etc.), my guess is that you're more motivated by getting something to work.

I'm assuming you've got styles for most of your app that would conflict with the landing page, so if the styles from app apply also to the landing page, the landing page looks funny, and vice versa. So my guess is that you're looking for a way to have some styles apply to the app, and other styles apply to the landing page.

For this, I would first of all bypass your regular layout - see [bypass application.html.erb in Rails app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9560093/bypass-application-html-erb-in-rails-app)

Then, I would update your regular layout to somehow indicate that it is the app and not the landing page. There are any number of ways to do this, but I might do the following:

application.html.erb:

`<body class='app'><!-- etc. -->`

landing_page.html.erb:

`<body class='landing_page'><!-- etc. -->`

Then, in your scss files, update it thus:

application.css.scss:

```
body.app {
  /* All your regular app styles */
}

body.landing_page {
  /* All your landing page styles */
}
```

Of course you can split those into multiple files, etc..

**TL;DR**
Unless you're running into loading time issues or you have some other reason why you really really don't want app styles loading for the landing page, then just put it all together but scope the styles so that they don't apply when they shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

You are already working in the Rails domain, so it would probably be easier to continue to stay in that domain.

In my opinion, the best/easiest thing to do would be to create a welcome controller. Create an empty index action in the controller and a view for that action. The view you are creating seems rather simple, so you can just prefix the class/id names (which don't seem like many) with welcome_ and this will differentiate them from your normal class/id names. The link for the homepage text will point to the index action of that particular controller.

Then you can create the root route in your routes.rb file to point to welcome#index.

Comment: Im not sure I understand. If I create a controller via rails g controller welcome index
This will bind welcome.css.scss to inherit application.css styling rules. I need the landing page to be completely independent from the files in myapp/app/assets/stylesheets and the application.css file. 
Do you think I can create css file example.css outside of the assets directory and then in view file point it to the example.css file?

Comment: Is there a reason you NEED the landing page style sheet to be independent from the apps stylesheets? Or is it solely so the css rules do t clash?

Comment: The reason that is specific to this issue is that I don't want the css in application.css effecting the landing page.